# git pull failing to pull changes from remote

Tags: git, github

My git log looks as follows:[image]

As I understand it origin/master and origin/HEAD are on the remote repository while master is on the local machine. A change was pushed to the repository (by me from another machine) creating commit 0e17adc. I now want to bring that change into my local repository. I thought the correct approach was to do:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

However this returns:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

Why does this occur? master appears to me to be out of sync with origin/master and I thought `git pull` did a `git fetch` and then `git merge` so should merge origin/master with master?

Comment: Because your master branch is not tracking the correct remote branch?

Comment: How do I know if it's tracking the remote branch and if it isn't how do I set it to track the remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand it origin/master and origin/HEAD are on the remote repository while master is on the local machine.

This isn't quite right in detail (and the details matter) but it's backed by the right idea: `origin/master` is in your local machine, but it's your Git's way of *remembering* what your Git got from their (origin's) Git.  When you run `git fetch` (or have `git pull` run `git fetch`), your Git calls up their Git at the URL your Git has stored along with the name `origin`.  Their Git lists their `master` and its commit hash ID, and your Git make sure that you have the commit(s) required, and then sets your own `origin/master` to remember their `master`.

> I now want to bring that change into my local repository. I thought the correct approach was to do:
>
> ```
> git checkout master
> git pull
> ```

That's one way that people typically do it.  (I prefer to avoid `git pull` myself and break out the individual commands.)

> However this returns:
>
> ```
> Already up-to-date.
> ```

If you run `git branch -vv` (verbose twice: very verbose) you should see something similar to this, but different (this is in a Git repository for Git):

```
* master          5be1f00a9 [origin/master] First batch after 2.16
```

The thing in square brackets here, `origin/master`, is the current *upstream* setting for `master`.  Each branch can have one (and only one) upstream, which you can set with `git branch --set-upstream-to`.

When you run `git pull` (or break it down into its components as I do), Git:

1. runs `git fetch`: the other Git to fetch from defaults to the current branch's upstream's remote, in this case the `origin` part of `origin/master`; then
2. runs a second Git command, usually `git merge`: the argument to this command depends on what your Git got from the other Git, plus the rest of the upstream setting.

There are, again, a bunch of finicky details that could matter, if some settings are badly broken, but in short, if `git branch -vv` shows `origin/master` as the upstream, then:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

should perform the equivalent of what happens when you run `git pull` ... and that should *not* result in the `git log` output you are showing in your image.  So at this point my best guess is that the upstream of `master` is not set correctly.

You can run `git branch -vv` to view it, or use:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name "master@{upstream}"
```

which in my case prints:

```
refs/remotes/origin/master
```

(I put the quotes around `master@{upstream}` above because some command line interpreters do funny things with unquoted braces sometimes, but most of the time you should not need this).

If the upstream is wrong, and you're on `master` and want to fix it, run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

This assumes your Git version is at least 1.8.0, when `--set-upstream-to` was added.  In an older Git you can use:

```
git config branch.master.remote origin
git config branch.master.merge master
```

(the `git branch --set-upstream` command—note the lack of `-to` on the end here—is much too difficult to use correctly; avoid it).

Comment: This is really helpful and I've managed to fix the issue which was related to the branch not pointing to master upstream. One question: Does`git fetch origin` retrieve everything from the remote into the local version of the remote, `origin`. i.e. if there are changes on branch `test` on the remote as well as branch `master`, does fetch pull these as well? (Or in other words why `git fetch origin` and not `git fetch origin/master`?)

Comment: @218: `git fetch origin` has your Git call up origin's Git and list all its branches. Then (this part is controlled by your `remote.origin.fetch` but I assume it's set normally here) your Git downloads all their commits that they have that you don't, that you need to complete the operation; and after that, *your* Git sets all your `origin/*` names to match all their branch names. Remember that a branch name just stores *one* hash ID, so your `origin/*` names also store one hash ID. This fetch operation simply updates *all* your remote-tracking names, while also downloading everything. (cont'd)

Comment: You can instead run `git fetch origin master` (note: not `git fetch origin/master` and not `git fetch origin origin/master`). This tells your Git to call up `origin` just like before; but this time, when they list their branches and hash IDs, your Git should find their `master`, and transfer only the commits required by that hash ID, and then set your own `origin/master` to remember their `master` tip commit. A later `git fetch origin` will get the rest of everything. If you limit each `git fetch`, that will make each `git fetch` slightly faster, at the expense of a later *unlimited* (cont'd)

Comment: ... `git fetch` going slower. It's basically a tradeoff: do you want to save 0.013 seconds now to spend them tomorrow, or just get everything now and save 0.021 seconds tomorrow? Or maybe the numbers will go the other way. Unless the repository is really huge, though, these numbers will generally all be tiny, and there's no good reason to keep limiting each fetch.

Comment: @218: The really tricky thing is the renaming stuff, but it will make sense when you realize: The other Git is a Git repository. They have their own branches. If they've changed *their* `master` and added a `develop`, where will your Git store *your* previous `master` and your independent `develop`? The answer is that your Git *renames* all their branches as they come over. That's where `origin/master` comes from: it's your Git's *renamed* memory of their Git's `master`. Most commands work locally, so they use the renamed memory versions; but `git fetch` and `git push` talk to the other Git.